# Black hole and lepton number conservation

Tags: black-holes, conservation-laws, leptons

Can falling of an electron into a black be treated as a process in which energy, charge, spin (angular momentum) and **lepton number** of the system are conserved?

Imagine a small volume of space that at $t_0$ contained no particles. Then N neutrons enter those volume of space. If N is sufficiently large they can form a black hole ($bh_0$). After its formation, $bh_0$ can absorb a proton and an electron with formation of a bit more massive neutral black hole $bh_1$
$$N n \longrightarrow bh_0 \\
bh_0+ p^+ + e^- \longrightarrow bh_1 $$

The black hole will emit Hawking-radiation and, therefore, will evaporate after sufficiently long time with formation of photons (and possibly a small number of other particles). So, for distant observer, $bh_1$ can be treated as an intermediate state of neutrons, proton and electron converting into photons.

$$N n + p^+ + e^- \longrightarrow (IntermediateState) \longrightarrow M \gamma$$

This process violates lepton number conservation.

The question is what is the best explanation of this thought experiment:

- lepton number is not conserved in interactions including gravitation forces, so there is a tiny probability of proton-electron interaction with formation of photon(s).
- black holes ara characterized not only by mass, charge, and angular momentum(spin), but also by leptonic number that affects which particles are formed upon black hole evaporation (contradicts "The no-hair theorem")
- falling of an electron into black hole should be accomplished by emission of a neutrino $$e^- + bh_0 \longrightarrow bh_1 + \nu_e, $$ where $bh_0$ and $bh_1$ are black hole before and after electron absorption.

Comment: @Apoorv Khurasia I read the mentioned question before asking my one but it does not answer my problem. If to read non-specialized literature, Hawking-radiation, "no-hair theorem", and lepton number conservation appear to be widely accepted.  But for me it seems there is some inconsistency between those three statements. So I would like to know if I do a mistake in my conclusions, simply did not find a proper explanation, or this problem is not yet  understood.

Comment: I cannot say if this problem is not yet understood as this is not my area of expertise but I personally doubt if lepton/baryon numbers are really conserved quantities. This may be my own lack of deeper understanding but there is indeed an outstanding baryogensis and leptogensis problem which remains an unsolved problem in physics.